# Layerlist drawable doesn't stretch nicely

Tags: android, android-drawable, layer-list, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I'm starting to learn android layer list and working with drawables.
I'm trying to create a simple line with a circle at each end:
[image]

I came up with a layerlist as shown below. It works good but the problem is when I run it on various screen sizes the circles either separate from the line or the get pushed in and fall in on the line.

I want the shape to resize as is and not get deformed on different screen sizes. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="300dp" android:gravity="center_horizontal|left">
        <shape android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="700"
        android:thickness="5dp"
        android:useLevel="false">

            <solid android:color="#fff" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item 
        android:bottom="13dp"
        android:right="53dp"
        android:left="53dp"
        android:top="13dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
        <solid android:color="#fff" />

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
         android:right="300dp" android:gravity="center_horizontal|right">
        <shape 
            android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadiusRatio="700"
            android:thickness="5dp"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <solid android:color="#fff" />

        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <solid android:color="#ec0b0b" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#054b89" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_online"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:right="50dp" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_online"
        android:gravity="right" />

</layer-list>
```

> android:drawable="@drawable/ic_online"

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="10dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#05b714"
        android:pathData="M12,12m-10,0a10,10 0,1 1,20 0a10,10 0,1 1,-20 0"/>
</vector>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]